# Using .load() to load pages en livesearch but get result 2 or 3 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my code, I try to make a website that opens several pages from a navigation bar. The page loads perfect, but after opening a page and when I live search for a result on that page it shows a double result, 2x index 2x first page ...

If I open the same page twice and then livesearch it, then I see the result 3 times.

Can somebody see what the problem is?

```js
  //Load page in #container
  $('[data-target]').click( function (e) { 
    //$('#container').load($(this).attr('href'));
    var target = $($(this).attr('data-target'));
    target.load($(this).attr('href'));
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent anchor from changing window.location
  });  

  //Live search
  $('#search').keyup(function(){
    $('#container').empty();
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data){
      $.each(data, function(key, val){
        if(val.name.search(myExp) != -1) {
          var newDiv = $('<div class="target">').append(val.name).click(function(){
            $('#container').load(val.doc+" "+val.shortname);
          });
          newDiv.append('</div>');
          //alert(newDiv);
          $('#container').append(newDiv);
        }
      });
    });
    newDiv = "";
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that your AJAX request takes some time. You empty the container, then make the request. While it's loading another key is pressed which initiates yet another AJAX request. When the two requests complete, they both assume the container was already cleared and just append the result, hence the double result.

Try clearing container just before appending:

```
$('#container').empty().append(newDiv);
```

Full code:

```js
  //Load page in #container
  $('[data-target]').click( function (e) { 
    //$('#container').load($(this).attr('href'));
    var target = $($(this).attr('data-target'));
    target.load($(this).attr('href'));
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent anchor from changing window.location
  });  

  //Live search
  $('#search').keyup(function(){
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data){
      $('#container').empty()
      $.each(data, function(key, val){
        if(val.name.search(myExp) != -1) {
          var newDiv = $('<div class="target">').append(val.name).click(function(){
            $('#container').load(val.doc+" "+val.shortname);
          });
          newDiv.append('</div>');
          //alert(newDiv);
          $('#container').append(newDiv);
        }
      });
    });
    newDiv = "";
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that fixed the problem with the double results, but now it only shows one anwer at a time and not the full searchresult.

Comment: So what exactly does your json request returns? Not the whole result set?

Comment: If i uncomment alert(newDiv) then i see every result that I want to show but it disapeares and shows the last result in the list. I think its because of the empty() function it cleans the container before it adds a new result?